# Why is my download speed around 4Mb/s when I have 50Mb/s connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, download, internet-connection

I have a fiber Internet connections. I've tested it at ~50Mb/s. But I downloaded some files on chrome and speed came out around 4-5Mb/s. **Why is this so?
Please suggest some ways how I can achieve 50Mb/s download speed?**

Comment: Connect a computer directly to your ISP modem Ethernet port and test the speed with Speedtest.net    .   Download a large file and test the speed.  Good or bad. The issue you have may be (1) your internal networking gear and / or (2) the site you are downloading from - busy sites tend to be slow.

Comment: Confirm that you have a 50mega**bit** connection and are measuring in bit/s rather than expecting 50M**byte**. a 50M**bit** would have a download speed around 5-6M**bytes** per second after overheads.

Comment: You are, 50Megabits per second = 6.25 MegaBytes per second...